# iOS App screen becomes black after click event, remains black after subsequent launches

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am facing a weird problem in my app. There is a `viewcontroller` in which I have two buttons. In one particular state of the application, on pressing these buttons, the app window goes black.

After this, if I open the app after removing it from memory, the window goes black again immediately after the root `viewcontroller`'s `viewdidappear` method.

There is no crash, no exception is raised and the background processes keep on logging their activity.

Can somebody tell me how I can go about debugging this problem? Any suggestions will help.

Comment: Did you tried **clean & build**

Comment: yeah, i have tried that, but to no avail.